# Plotly Dash app deploy on Hereko, App takes 6 minutes to load in Local

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, plotly, plotly-dash

I made a plotly dash application. It has 4 different visualization, including geo spatial map. In my local machine it takes around 6 minutes to load. It runs fine after that. Now i try to deploy on Heroku free service and it's now working, giving me an application error. I tried to check my logs, it says Erros H20 and Error H10. I read that the Heroku free can only have dynos for 30 seconds.
Can someone help me with that?

Comment: The H20 error indicates that you app takes too long to boot, i.e. to remove the error you must reduce the app boot time.

Comment: I used the Heroku preboot in the gunicorn server but it's not working. My app in local uses 6 minutes to start, that's my question. How can I deploy on the heroku free service ?

Comment: You should rewrite your app so that it starts in < 75 seconds, then it should work.